# Dropdown in Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a field in Django `models.py` which will render as a dropdown and user can select the options from there.

If I have 5 choices:

- GREEN
- BLUE
- RED
- ORANGE
- BLACK

How should I write my code in `models.py` and `Forms.py` so that the template renders it like a dropdown element?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Specify CharField or IntegerField with `choices` option in your model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices and use ModelForm https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/.

Answer (score 116):

From model to template :

**models.py**

```
COLOR_CHOICES = (
    ('green','GREEN'),
    ('blue', 'BLUE'),
    ('red','RED'),
    ('orange','ORANGE'),
    ('black','BLACK'),
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
  color = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default='green')
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['color']
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateMyModelView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'myapp/template.html'
    success_url = 'myapp/success.html'
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

or to display your select field only :

```
{{ form.color }}
```

Comment: You should also include a `urls.py`, where you have something like (Django 2.0+), 
`urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('abc', views.CreateMyModelView.as_view(), name='abc')
]`

Comment: Can we make it without "create" button?

Comment: What if i want to select two or three coses like ["green","blue"]

Comment: NameError: name 'ModelForm' is not defined

Comment: After several months I was unable to get this to work. The form is empty with just the botton.

Answer (score 7):

An even better option in **Django version 3.0** and higher:

You can use inner classes which inherit from the new models.TextChoices class. That also provides a convenient way to provide human readable (and translatable) labels, as well as a nice interface for the programmer.

[Official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Student(models.Model):

    class YearInSchool(models.TextChoices):
        FRESHMAN = 'FR', _('Freshman')
        SOPHOMORE = 'SO', _('Sophomore')
        JUNIOR = 'JR', _('Junior')
        SENIOR = 'SR', _('Senior')
        GRADUATE = 'GR', _('Graduate')

    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YearInSchool.choices,
        default=YearInSchool.FRESHMAN,
    )

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.year_in_school in {
            self.YearInSchool.JUNIOR,
            self.YearInSchool.SENIOR,
        }

###########
# human readable text can then be called by...
Student.YearInSchool.Junior.label

# or from an instance by <instance>.get_<innerclass name>_display() like...
student_inst.get_yearinschool_display()
```