# Dropdown list in Django

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I have copied all the code from this post
[Dropdown in Django Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130706/dropdown-in-django-model)

What do I have to do to make this list visible?
When I run manage.py makemigrations or managepy migrate it tells that there are no changes.

My code.
**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse('<h1>Witamy w aplikacji dla najlepszych inwestorów!</h1>')

  class CreateMyModelView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = 'myapp/template.html'
    success_url = 'myapp/success.html'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

COLOR_CHOICES = (
    ('green','GREEN'),
    ('blue', 'BLUE'),
    ('red','RED'),
    ('orange','ORANGE'),
    ('black','BLACK'),
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
  color = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default='green')
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['color']
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Everything is the same and when I run my server 
[only this appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWbFU.png)

What might be an issue?

Comment: You do not trigger your `CreateMyModelView`, but your `index` view.

Answer (score 0):

You must route the view in **urls.py** to `CreateMyModelView` so it can be accessed. You are now only returning an **HttpResponse** on the index view method.

You can change so that the `CreateView` is the index view like this:

```
from .views import CreateMyModelView

...
    path('', CreateMyModelView.as_view(), name='create_my_model_view')
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now there is such an error
                                         path('', CreateMyModelView.as_view(), name='create_my_model_view'),
NameError: name 'CreateMyModelView' is not defined

Comment: @Kokopas You must also import your class that you defined in views.py in the urls.py.

Comment: haven't we arleady imported it with his line above which You posted?

Comment: @Kokopas No, you always have to import it such like: `from some_app.views import AboutView` read more here: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)