# Add Radio button in default Django form:

Tags: python, django, forms, radio-button

I think I have written the correct code. But this gender radio button is not appearing in my form.

This is my model view.

```
 class Charter(models.Model):
        CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Others')]
        Gender = forms.ChoiceField(label='Gender', widget= 
        forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
        created_at = models.DateField()
        First_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        Cell_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
        created_at = models.DateField()
```

This is my forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

```
class CharterForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model= Charter
            fields = '__all__'
            widgets = {
                'Gender': forms.RadioSelect()
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this similar link: [Dropdown in Django Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130706/dropdown-in-django-model)

or

Refer to [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices) for more info

```
CHOICES = (
   ('M', 'Male'), 
   ('F', 'Female'),
   ('O', 'Others'),
)
```