# How to Display value in Drop-down in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to display value in dropdown from databse, and I am getting value through `id`, but it's displaying only one value which is save in my database. But i want all dropdown value.
Please let me know how i can display all values in dropdown.

Here is my `models.py` file where dropdown code is written...

```
TYPES = [
 ('A', 'Active'),
 ('D', 'Not Active'),
]
```

and these values are savingin another modes using choices,and `A` and `D` are storing in my Database.
Here is my `views.py` file..

```
def getdata(request, id):
    display=Mymodel.objects.filter(pk=id).first()
    context={'display':display}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

and here is my `page.html` file where I am displaying data in dropdown..

```
<select name='types'>
   <option value="{{display.types}}">{{display.get_types_display}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

but this is displaying in dropdown `Active` values only, but i want both values, I want to edit data using this form. ANd if `A` is saved in my database then in default `Active` should be select and if `D` is saved in my database then `Not Active` should be select in default, rest values should be display in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have form and to be able to add data, then you need to create model form in forms.py. Unfortunately you haven't written your model code, just choices that you wish to use (add Mymodel definition - it should be named MyModel to conform to Camel notation, but it is not an error).

In your Mymodel you should have field like this:

```
some_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPES)
```

When you use model in form, than you should use special version of form called ModelForm. It is defined like this:

```
class MymodelForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Mymodel
    fields = '__all__'

some_type = ModelChoiceField(
    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
)
```

You should also update your views.py, but this is generally how it is done in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this similar question: [Dropdown in Django Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130706/dropdown-in-django-model)
and refer to Val F's answer

or Check out the [official Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Turn Types into a tuple

```
TYPES = (
 ('A', 'Active'),
 ('D', 'Not Active'),
)
```