# How to pass selected value from dropdown in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, dropdown

I have a combobox onchange of selection in need to load the field with list of items. I tried various method to pass the selected dropdown value to a method. I tried to call a javascript method in from datalist onChange event but it didn't work. how can we achieve this?

I am tried for full day but unfortunately no luck.
SearchForm

```
class Searchform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Search
        fields = '__all__'
```

Model.

```
CIVIL_ENGINEERING = 'CIVIL_ENGINEERING'
BIM = 'BIM'
CAD = 'CAD'
RAILWAY_SYSTEM = 'RAILWAY_SYSTEM'
SUPERVISION = 'SUPERVISION'
INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY = 'INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY'

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('CIVIL_ENGINEERING' , 'Civil Engineering'),
    ('BIM' , 'BIM'),
    ('CAD' , 'CAD'),
    ('RAILWAY_SYSTEM' , 'Railway System'),
    ('SUPERVISION' , 'Supervision'),
    ('INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY' , 'Information Technology'),
)

class Search(models.Model):
    category_choices = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=True)
```

VIEW

```
def update(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = {
            'choices': maincategory._meta.get_field('category').choices
        }
        return render(request, 'update.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<div>
   {{searchform.category_choices}}
</div>
```

[image: Which gives me this]

Comment: Have you tried to create as a form? If not, [this thread could be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131029/11911360)

Comment: @Ediz I tried with form.. I am successfully able to display the dropdown list .. but when i select the item from the list. I not able to get the value of selected item.. any clue to get the value from the list. "Selected"

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a value option but no select input. here's a simple snippet. can you try it like this with your for loop?

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: and probably with the correct id. which looks 'category' for yours.

Comment: I have edited the question. I need to populate the dropdown based on selection.. if it Bim i need to populate second combo box with BIM skills set.... sorry I am a noob in python django.. I need some help badly.  now its been two days.