# How to create dropdown box with forms.ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to add a dropdown box of choices in my form. What I tried:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Car

class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    owner_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Owner Name', required=True)
    car_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Car.CarTypes.choices, label='Car Type', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('owner_name', 'car_type')
```

It adds the `car_type` field to the form but it's not a dropdown for some reason (it's a regular empty box you could fill). The `CarTypes` looks like:

```
    class CarTypes(models.TextChoices):
        X = 'some_x'
        Y = 'somy_y'
        # ...
```

What could be the reason?

In my `Car` class I have: `car_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=CarTypes.choices, default=CarTypes.X)`. Could be it? I think `CharField` makes it empty box. But changing it to `ChoiceField` ends with: `module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ChoiceField'`. How to solve it?

I tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130706/dropdown-in-django-model) but it uses a tuple instead of a class. From the example there I see they use tuple of two-value-tuples like `(('a','A'),('b','B'))` and I'm using class. Could it be the reason?

In my html I have:

```
    <form method="post" class="form-group">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-3">
          <label for="{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ field.label }}" name="{{ field.name }}">
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <hr class="mb-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Submit New Car</button>
    </form>
```

And the Car looks like:

```
class Car(models.Model):

    class CarTypes(models.TextChoices):
        X = 'some_x'
        Y = 'somy_y'
        # ...

    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=CarTypes.choices, default=CarTypes.X)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner_name
```

Comment: Share also your model `Car`. Django vesion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to override your model fields. See [**Field types**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types) - [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)

> If the model field has choices set, then the form field’s widget will
> be set to Select, with choices coming from the model field’s choices.

The following code should do what you want:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Car

class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Car 
        fields = ['owner_name', 'car_type']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['owner_name'].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control"})
        # or iterate over field to add class for each field
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class':"form-control"})
```

You can add any html attribute in `__init__` method.

**html:**

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-3">
      <label for="{{ form.owner_name.label }}">{{ form.owner_name.label }}</label>
      {{ form.owner_name }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="{{ form.car_type.label }}">{{ form.car_type.label }}</label>
        {{ form.car_type }}
    </div>
  <hr class="mb-4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Submit New Car</button>
</form>
```

Or You can use [**`{{ form.as_p }}`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) - [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) will render them wrapped in `<p>` tags

**UPDATE**

---

Render form manually:

```
<form method="post" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="{{ form.owner_name.label }}">{{ form.owner_name.label }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ form.owner_name.auto_id }}" name="{{ form.owner_name.name }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label for="{{ form.car_type.label }}">{{ form.car_type.label }}</label>
        <select id="{{ form.car_type.auto_id }}" name="{{ form.car_type.name }}">
        {% for value, label in form.fields.car_type.choices %}
            <option value="{{ value }}"{% if form.car_type.value == value %} selected{% endif %}>{{ label }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
  <hr class="mb-4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Submit New Car</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I used `{{ field }}` instead of my `input` part. But how do I customize it with `class="form-control" id="{{ field.label }}" name="{{ field.name }}"`?

Comment: @vesii, You can add any html attribute in __init__ method.

Comment: Is it possible to do in the HTML itself?

Comment: You have to render your input than manually.

Comment: Also, do you have an idea why `__init__` is not being executed? Added prints both in `Meta` and in `__init__` but `__init__` does not print anything (and does not add the form-control).

Comment: @vesii, I updated my answer with rendering form manually.

Comment: `__init__`  is the method of `CarForm`. It should be working. If it not working share your updated  `CarForm` in chat.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method of `Choices` :-

models.py

```
choices = [
    ('choice1', 'choice1'),
    ('choice2',"choice2"),
    ('choice3',"choice3")
]

class Car(models.Model):

    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    car_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=choices, default='choice1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner_name
```

And then don't forget to make `migrations`

Refer this ---> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices

Comment: I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'` because `forms.ModelForm` does not have choices in `CharField`.

Comment: How do you keep it class though?

Comment: Just remove the `choice Class CarTypes` in your existing model.

Answer (score 0):

For Django 3.1, you can achieve this with `widgets`. Here's how you can get it done:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select, TextInput
from .models import Car

class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('owner_name', 'car_type')
        widgets = {
            'owner_name': TextInput(),
            'car_type': Select(),
        }
```

And Model should look like this:

````
    class Car(models.Model):
        choices = [('X':'some_x'), ('Y': 'some_y']
        owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
        car_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=choices, default='some_y')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.owner_name```
````

Comment: Does `forms.ChoiceField` `ModelForm`  have  `choices`? From the second answer I got `TypeError: __init__()
got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices' ` because forms.ModelForm does not have choices in CharField