# Django Form Dropdown List Won't Display

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a dropdown list in a form. I followed this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131029/6307889). If I use `{{ form.as_p }}`, the dropdown list renders just fine. But rendering the form using `as_p` looks terrible. Instead, I loop through the form fields and access their parameters so I can stylize the inputs. I try to catch the field of the dropdown list using an if-statement with condition `field.widget.input_type == "select"`. When the page renders, I should see "This is where my dropdown goes" where my dropdown list field is supposed to be. But that doesn't happen, the field gets rendered as a text input like every other field, so my if-statement is not working. I debugged my view function and confirmed that the field corresponding to the dropdown list does have parameter `.widget.input_type == "select"`. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<form action="{% url 'myapp:newrecord' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            {% if field.widget.input_type == "select" %}
                <p>This is where my dropdown goes.</p>
            {% else %}
              <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="{{ field.html_name }}" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" placeholder="{{ field.label }}" required>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>This shouldn't be empty but it is.</p>
    {% endfor %}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

`{% if field.field.widget.input_type == "select" %}`