# how to make a dropdown selection in a CreateView field- Django

Tags: python, django

i'm adding a new field(location) to my PostCreateView

and I want to be able to select that field if it's already in the database. (like idk New York)

it does show up but obv its not a dropdown.

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'location'] 
    success_url = '/'
```

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.location


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")


    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I've tried to add this

```
widgets= {
        'location': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

right underneath to my class PostCreateView, but I guess it doesn't work since I don't use forms.py and instead I use class PostCreateView inside of views.py

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py` file, the location component should be a **ForeignKey**. In this case, your model should look like so:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When you add that field to your form or defined fields from your *CreateView* it will appear as a dropdown.

Comment: gives me this error: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'blog_post' with primary key '3' has an invalid foreign key: blog_post.location_id contains a value '' that does not have a corresponding value in blog_location.id.

Comment: If your location list is small, you can add the preferred locations manually in your code by using `choices`.  In the event you have more locations, you can just add these to DB and they will render as ForeignKey. If you choose to go the ForeignKey route consider starting your DB afresh. Otherwise checkout this Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130706/dropdown-in-django-model